# Is it possible to attach a file to the form confirmation email message?

Tags: cognito-forms

We would like to attach a document in the confirmation email message. Is this possible? I try to use "uploaded files" but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer a way to upload a file to Cognito Forms, to then include the file in the email confirmation. You can upload the file to your website, then provide a link to that file in the email confirmation.